# Вопрос фронтендерам

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь сделать всплывающее окно, но не обычное, а как в сайте AliExpress: всплывающее окно появляется, но её "тень" перекрывает все объекты, кроме header. "Тень" работает как отдельный div с position: fixed, но ведь по дефолту она должна абсолютно всё перекрывать. Как сделать так, чтобы она не перекрывала конкретный объект (в нашем случае шапку сайта)?

Comment: Может быть [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)?

Comment: Я пробовал, но не получается (хотя по идее должно было получиться)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение.

Нужно было применить `position: sticky` и `z-index` поставить больше, чем у "тени".